# Perl and MS SQL thread issue

Tags: multithreading, perl, win32ole

I have a Perl application on Windows which uses threads which run in parallel. Each thread accesses an MSSQL database.

I understand that I can't use [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) because it is not thread safe.

Could you suggest me some another suitable solution for doing this?

- Create a Windows service, which will access the database as a single thread and Perl will use this service?
- Create another Perl app "server", which will access to DB as single thread app, and the Perl threads will use this service?
- Use `Win32::OLE` (DBI) library only in child threads or by some safe way?

I don't know what the right way is, and what the ways to solve it might be.

Comment: I apologise if I'm being dim, but what does DBI have to do with Win32::OLE? I see no problem with allowing multithreaded access to a database using [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)

Comment: I thought, that perl DBI library use in my case Win32::OLE library and thus is not save connect to database by $con = DBI->connect("dbi:ADO:...).

Comment: You will need to use an ODBC connection using the [DBD::ODBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC) driver, but [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) isn't dependent on any modules other than some build-time requirements and the `DBD` drivers.

Comment: I tried ODBC connection, if I create new connection in each perl thread, so far everything is working without errors. Thank you !

Comment: I'm pleased that it's working for you. You should take note of the warning in my answer, that you must set `$dbh->{AutoInactiveDestroy} = 1` directly after the `connect` call for safer multithreading operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) isn't dependent on anything other than the usual build and test modules that are used during installation

There is no `DBD` driver for SQL Server (I'm not clear why. Perhaps someone would enlighten me?) so you will need to use an ODBC connection using the [`DBD::ODBC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC) driver

I'm unsure how `DBI` behaves under threads, and I suggest you use `fork` instead which is emulated on Windows versions of Perl. You will need to set `$dbh->{AutoInactiveDestroy} = 1` to prevent processes from auto-destroying database and statement handles when they shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Borodin why not use [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class.pod) ?

It is thread safe. Maybe you should explain better the way your application have access to database. It seems that you have a "Windows server" that is a sort of Perl Module that use Win32::OLE and this server acctually talks with the database.

Comment: There is a huge learning curve for `DBIx::Class`, and it is dependent on a vast number of non-core subsidiary modules: `Class::Accessor::Grouped`, `Class::C3::Componentised`, `Config::Any`, `Context::Preserve`, `DBD::SQLite`, `Data::Dumper::Concise`, `Data::Page`, `MRO::Compat`, `Module::Find`, `Package::Stash`, `Path::Class`, `SQL::Abstract`, `Scope::Guard`, `Sub::Name`, `Test::Deep`, `Try::Tiny` and `namespace::clean`. I am certain that a simple `DBI` application will serve.